# Select button updates C3js graph without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple select options, and I want my C3js charts to update once all the options have been selected. Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#op,#op2').on('change', function () {
        if ($('#op').val() && $('#op2').val()) {   
            alert("its working?");
            var url = "/php/test.php"; 
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: $("#form").serialize(), 
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       alert(data); 
                   }
                 });
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
});
```

I also know that there are multiple examples on the c3js reference site to loading/unloading data. My `test.php` file gets all the new values that I want to put on my charts. I just don't know how to make a bridge between those values and my charts.

Also, I'm not sure if I should just remake new graphs each time a new option is selected, or if I should try the load/unload c3js method. I don't know how to connect my php file values to

```
<div id="chart"></div>             
<script>
    var Completed = <?php echo json_encode($var1) ?>;
    var Missed = <?php echo json_encode($var2) ?>;
    var json_data_a = {"x_label":IDs,"Completed":Completed,"Missed":Missed};

   var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: "#chart",
        data: {
            x: 'x_label',
            json: json_data_a
        },
        axis: {
          x: {
            type: 'category',

            label: {
              text: 'ID',
              position: 'outer-center'
            }
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

My test.php file gets the new var1 and var2 values, but I just don't know how to make a connection between them and the graph without having to refresh the page. Is it possible to load/unload with AJAX? I feel like there's no way for me to connect the two.

For testing purposes, I tried adding:

```
success: function(data)
  {
       alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       chart.load({
          columns: [
              ['data1', 300, 100, 250, 150, 300, 150, 500],
              ['data2', 100, 200, 150, 50, 100, 250]
            ]
        });

}
```

to my success function, and got the stuff to load. All of my php variables that I want to stick to the graph are in php. How do I get them to JS so that I can load them into my graph?  When I try this:

```
var Completed = <?php echo json_encode($completed) ?>;
```

into my success function, and I ended up getting this error:

`Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'.     var Completed = <?php echo json_encode($completed) ?>;`

I want to do something similar to this:

```
<?php
    ....
    json_encode($VarA);
?>
```

then, I want to put that into a JS var...

```
var A = <?php echo json_encode($VarA)?>;
....
```

Then I can stick it into an obj...

```
var json_obj = {"x_axis": VarA, "Some Data": VarB, ....}
```

I just don't know how to get the php code out of my url file so that I can save it as a js variable and move forward..